# different images depending on user screen size

Tags: ios, swift, background, uibutton

I'm working on a project where I have a `UIButton` going from horizontally from edge to edge of the screen. The button in the `storyboard` is `600 x 242`.
I'm set a background image for the `UIButton` which is also `600 x 242` however my problem is that when running the app on different iPhone screen sizes it just chops off part of the image on the left and right.

[image]

Would it be possible to use a different image deepening on the screen size to have everything I need to fit in the UIButton on all screen sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To some extent this can be achieved with size classes. But a much better approach in this case it to set the images in code and choses the image depending on the button size. Or you could try to change the content mode of the button.

Comment: Thank you so much! Setting the images in code was a great idea and truly helped me a lot! :D